# FusedLocation Longitude Issue

Tags: java, android, location, android-fusedlocation

It's strange how I get a totally invalid longitude from using Fused Location API.

Understand that longitude ranges from 0 - 180, It's funny how I receive 189 from the API.

[Here is an image of the Location Logs with Invalid Longitude](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rkiTn.png)

[image]

Can anyone tell me what's going on? Here are some code snippets:

```
    mLocationRequest.setInterval(INTERVAL);
    mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(FASTEST_INTERVAL);
    mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
```

-

```
    mFusedLocationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this);
    mFusedLocationClient.requestLocationUpdates(mLocationRequest, mLocationCallback, null);
```

Am I missing anything out? It doesn't happen all the time on all users, just certain users randomly

---

Logging:
This is a location service update that should run every 10 seconds (interval) and 5 seconds (fastest interval). I'm saving the location details in the app at the location callback using a static function like so:

```
        mLocationCallback = new LocationCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onLocationResult(LocationResult locationResult) {
                if (locationResult == null) {
                    return;
                }

                for (Location location : locationResult.getLocations()) {
                    MainApplication.setCurrentLocation(location);
                }
            }
        };
```

And every 10 seconds, I'm emitting a socket event to the server like so:

```
        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
        obj.put("id", id);
        obj.put("lat", String.valueOf(MainApplication.getCurrentLocation().getLatitude()));
        obj.put("long", String.valueOf(MainApplication.getCurrentLocation().getLongitude()));
        obj.put("handler", String.valueOf(MainApplication.getCurrentLocation().getProvider()));
        obj.put("version", Utils.getAppVersion(MainApplication.getContext()));

        if (mSocket.connected()) {
            mSocket.emit("set location", obj);
        }
```

Comment: show how you log it

Comment: I'm sending the details into a socket.io server (business requirements). I'm simply printing the logs out from the socket console which have invalid latitude/longitude from the client.

Comment: then show how you send it

Comment: Updated the thread. Let me know if you need more details.

Comment: [on behalf of @EricC ] I filed a ticket with Google's official bug tracker for this issue. I read your stackoverflow post and thought it was a platform bug. The issue I filed can be found here: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/119582508.

If you have any more details to provide on how to reproduce this issue, then that would be appreciated if you could add them to the bug tracker ticket I filed.